# How to display Google captcha?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My Google captcha has had the ends chopped off, particularly the right end in both mobile mobile and desktop?

Why is this?

I have the following html:

```
"wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" 
name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Message<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea 
name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><div class="anr_captcha_field"><div id="anr_captcha_field_1" 
class="anr_captcha_field_div"></div></div><span class="wpcf7-form- 
control-wrap g-recaptcha-response"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>. 
</div></div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-footer">
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

And the following css:

```
#anr_captcha_field_1 {overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 0px;
transform: scale(0.9);
transform-origin: left top;
margin-left:35px; background-color: #fff; border: none;
}

@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) 
{#anr_captcha_field_1 {

overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 0px;
transform: scale(0.9);
transform-origin: left top;
margin-left:10px; background-color: #fff; border: none;
}}
```

The problem arose because I wanted to centre the capture in desktop, now the right end's chopped off.

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/contact-us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your CSS:

```
.anr_captcha_field {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .anr_captcha_field {
      margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

This should help solve your problem

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't that be `#anr` and if not why not?

Comment: Also, won't that put it out of line with the rest of the form?

Comment: Everything is fine, do not worry about anything. CSS only affects the appearance, and from this I can see everything looks elegant. You can even set: `margin-left: -6px;` so Captcha would be more in the middle. To make sure you have more confidence I checked it on several browsers, on different sizes and with different magnification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the max width of your form as well. it is blocking the captcha.

```
  @media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px){
      .wpcf7 {
          max-width: 330px;
          padding: 0px;
      }
    }

    .rc-anchor-normal {
        height: 74px;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just decreased it as it was showing a larger width in some browsers. The current width is great because it shows the same across all browsers. So how to maintain this current width and show capture?also, why should form be blocking captcha when it's above it?